# Asignar ruta a imagen

Tags: javascript

Tengo esta función que toma una foto directamente desde la webcam, pero la guarda en descargas. Quisiera saber cómo podría poner una dirección en específico desde aquí mismo por que sé que se puede cambiar eso desde el navegador, pero la foto la necesito guardar directamente en una carpeta dentro del proyecto desde que se hace la toma, este es mi código:

```
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
Captura.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (video.srcObject && video.srcObject.active) {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    video.style.display = "none";
    canvas.style.display = "block";
    Captura.style.display = "none";
    TomarOtra.style.display = "inline-block";
    let foto = canvas.toDataURL();
    let enlace = document.createElement("a");
    enlace.download = "FotoCapturada.png";
    enlace.href = foto;
    enlace.click();
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
  } else {
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML =
      "No se ha otorgado permiso para acceder a la cámara";
  }
});
```